# Excel count number of columns that contain the number 1 within text values

Tags: excel

I am trying to come up with a simple solution to count the number of columns containing certain numbers. It can be a formula or a function.

The cells will contain a mix of numbers and letters, i.e. Group 1, Section 11, Task 21, Lot1, Item-1, etc...

What I want to do is to count all the 1s only, and then the 2s, etc...Not the 21s, or 11s obviously.
There may be spaces, there may not be, nothing is too set in stone.
I am trying to make a formula work but am thinking I will need to do a function and call it from the cell I want the result in.  i.e. "=CountCols("1").

I can think of a function but it seems awful clunky, thought I would see if anyone had a more elegant way.
Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Also, the number may not be the last character in the text string, I forgot to include those possibilities, i.e. RY98 (1)

Comment: So with `RY98 (1)` and you were wanting to count `98` I would assume you do not want to count this as a match?

Comment: Correct.  I will only count from 1 to 15.  I don't need anything further. And there will never be any numbers lower than 60 in the RY texts.

Comment: It would be useful to see the function you thought of. If you could [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66353937/edit) to include it, it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

and thanks to everyone for viewing my question.

It was answered by a friend with who I shared this post. She created these two functions and they work a dream.
(I only needed to search Row 6 of each column in a particular worksheet.)

```
Public Function countColumnsWithWord(strToFind As String, sSheet As String) As Long
    
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim c As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim countOfFound As Long
    Dim iLastCol As Integer
    Dim strToSearch As String
    
    Set wks = Application.Worksheets(sSheet)
    
    iLastCol = wks.Cells(6, wks.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    'start in col 2
    'only row 6
    
    c = 2
    r = 6
    For c = 1 To iLastCol
      If wks.Cells(r, c).Value <> "" And Not IsEmpty(wks.Cells(r, c).Value) Then
        strToSearch = CStr(wks.Cells(r, c).Value)
        If findInString(strToFind, strToSearch) = True Then
          countOfFound = countOfFound + 1
        End If
      End If
    Next c

    countColumnsWithWord = countOfFound

End Function


Public Function findInString(strToFind As String, strToSearch As String)
  
  Dim isFound As Boolean
  Dim strCurrent As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim strToSearchLength As Long
  
  strToSearchLength = Len(strToSearch)
  
  isFound = False

  strCurrent = ""
  
  i = 1
  While i < strToSearchLength + 1 And isFound = False
    If Mid(strToSearch, i, 1) = " " Then
      If strToFind = strCurrent Then
        isFound = True
      Else
        strCurrent = ""
      End If
    Else
      strCurrent = strCurrent & Mid(strToSearch, i, 1)
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Wend
  
  If isFound = False And strToFind = strCurrent Then
    isFound = True
  End If

  findInString = isFound
    
End Function
```